# Ok Google "Note to self" with my app

Tags: android

I have been trying to read the Android Developers http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html#AppProvided but not got anywhere... How can I choose my app to pass the speech input from Google Now to my app?!

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.saltais.todo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- Dropbox -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:name="com.saltais.todo.NotesApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:allowBackup="true">

        <activity
            android:name="com.saltais.todo.gui.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="com.google.android.voicesearch.SELF_NOTE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.saltais.todo.gui.settings.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_settings"
            android:parentActivityName="com.saltais.todo.gui.main.MainActivity"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.saltais.todo.gui.main.MainActivity" />
        </activity>


        <!-- Dropbox -->
        <activity android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAuthActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="db-XXXXXXXXXXX" /><!--APP_KEY-->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="Dropbox Sync" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image: note to self img]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an Android Wear app with the note-taking voice action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457378/how-to-create-an-android-wear-app-with-the-note-taking-voice-action)

Comment: please search before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457378/how-to-create-an-android-wear-app-with-the-note-taking-voice-action

Comment: @Budius I have added the following code, but it's still not working!? Is there any permission missing maybe?