# android "SELF_NOTE" intent with cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent

I'm trying to add the "SELF_NOTE" intent to my cordova app, and it's not showing up in the "take a note" list of apps, in google now. 
I'm not trying to do anything with android wear, I just want my app to show up in the "take a note" app list in google now.

[image]

I tried to add the intent filter from this answer:
[How to create an Android Wear app with the note-taking voice action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457378/how-to-create-an-android-wear-app-with-the-note-taking-voice-action), to my manifest, but the app doesn't show in the list of apps of "take a note" or "note to self".

My app DOES show up in the "share" menu, for example from chrome.

[image]

My manifest:

```html
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="com.google.android.voicesearch.SELF_NOTE" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution finally.
There is a missing action that needs to be added to the manifest:

```
<action android:name="com.google.android.gm.action.AUTO_SEND" />
```